# Lubuntu wifi doesn't see 5ghz network on b43

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, broadcom, b43

I'm on Lubuntu 17.04 and unfortunately I don't see my local 5ghz wifi network. 
However I have no problem with connecting to 2.4ghz network after installing `firmware-b43-installer`. Also when I had Ubuntu 17.04 installed it didn't have any problems with seeing and connecting to any network (and I didn't have to install anything). I've checked similar answers but all lead to installing same b43 driver. So what is Lubuntu missing that is present on Ubuntu (17.04)?

My card is: `Broadcom Limited BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n`

Comment: Have you checked your specific Broadcom card, to see if it supports the 5GHz?  Not all wifi cards support dual-band.

Comment: As I mentioned it works fine on Ubuntu 17.04 and Windows, so I assume it's not a card problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` resolved the issue for me.